# How can I efficiently use tidyverse to lengthen my dataset so that there is one row per value according to the range stored in a column?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame that includes information about schools. The code below produces a toy example.

```
df <- tibble(grade_range = c('1-3','2-5','5-12'),
         school = c('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'),
         score = c(100, 110, 150))
```

The current data has one row per school, with a single character variable indicating the range of grade levels. I'd like to have a longer dataset, with one row per school-by-grade combination. The code below does the job, but it feels like a clumsy workaround, and I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to produce the same output.

```
df_long <- df %>% 
 mutate(low_grade = as.numeric(str_remove(str_extract(grade_range, '[[:digit:]]+-'),'-')),
         high_grade = as.numeric(str_remove(str_extract(grade_range, '-[[:digit:]]+'),'-')),
         fake_join_var = 1) %>% 
  left_join(data.frame(grade_level = c(1:12), fake_join_var = rep(1,12))) %>% 
  select(-fake_join_var) %>% 
  filter(grade_level >= low_grade & 
           grade_level <= high_grade)
```

(To be clear, df_long is exactly the output I want, I'm just wondering if there's a simpler way of producing it, maybe with purrr somehow?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your code is based on the difference between `low_grade` and `high_grade`, you still have to extract the numerical value from the string.

However, after that, you can simply `unnest()` the sequence between the two.

Here is the code:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(grade_range = c('1-3','2-5','5-12'),
             school = c('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'),
             score = c(100, 110, 150))

x = df %>% 
    mutate(
        low_grade = as.numeric(str_remove(str_extract(grade_range, '\\d+-'),'-')),
        high_grade = as.numeric(str_remove(str_extract(grade_range, '-\\d+'),'-')), 
        grade_level = map2(low_grade, high_grade, seq)
    ) %>% 
    unnest(grade_level)
x
#> # A tibble: 15 x 6
#>    grade_range school score low_grade high_grade grade_level
#>    <chr>       <chr>  <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>       <int>
#>  1 1-3         AAA      100         1          3           1
#>  2 1-3         AAA      100         1          3           2
#>  3 1-3         AAA      100         1          3           3
#>  4 2-5         BBB      110         2          5           2
#>  5 2-5         BBB      110         2          5           3
#>  6 2-5         BBB      110         2          5           4
#>  7 2-5         BBB      110         2          5           5
#>  8 5-12        CCC      150         5         12           5
#>  9 5-12        CCC      150         5         12           6
#> 10 5-12        CCC      150         5         12           7
#> 11 5-12        CCC      150         5         12           8
#> 12 5-12        CCC      150         5         12           9
#> 13 5-12        CCC      150         5         12          10
#> 14 5-12        CCC      150         5         12          11
#> 15 5-12        CCC      150         5         12          12


waldo::compare(df_long, x)
#> v No differences
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>